# Ansible unexpected eval of variables when using flattened

Tags: ansible, ansible-1.x

Have have a configuration file looking like that:

```
one:
  some: 'conf'

foo:
  -
    bar:
      - 'one'
      - 'two'
      - 'three'
  -
    bar:
      - 'one'
      - 'four'
      - 'five'
```

I want to get a list containing all strings of `bar` lists. I did this task:

```
- name: My amazing task
  debug: var=item
  with_flattened:
    - "{{ foo | map(attribute='bar') | list }}"
    #- Another lists here, but removed for simplicity
```

Here is the problem; the resulting list looks like this:

```
[{"one": "some": "conf"}, "two", "three", {"one": "some": "conf"}, "four", "five"]
```

Ansible seems to interpret the “one” variable previously set, ignoring the fact I’m expecting a string.

What did I do wrong? How can I get a list of strings out of the bar variables configuration?

(I use Ansible 1.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this very issue bare variables in `with_` loops don't work in recent Ansible releases.

To handle it in your case, use:

```
with_items: "{{ foo | map(attribute='bar') | sum(start=[]) | list }}"
```

`sum(start=[])` makes a list of lists flat here.